# "cinnamon and nutmeg" vs. "nutmeg and cinnamon"

Tags: expressions, pronunciation

I had a hunch that (at least in American usage) "cinnamon and nutmeg" was more common than "nutmeg and cinnamon". Sure enough, Google has 1.48M results vs. 829k results for these respectively; Bing shows 8.31M vs. 1.47M results respectively.

Why is this? It's hard to clearly make the case that one is easier to say than the other. Maybe because it's prosody -- the former feels more rythmical than the second? Or perhaps the "and" more naturally follows "cinnamon" than "nutmeg", because of the repeated "n" sound? Or is it likely just random linguistic evolution?

[Google Ngram viewer shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cinnamon%20and%20nutmeg%2C%20nutmeg%20and%20cinnamon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccinnamon%20and%20nutmeg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnutmeg%20and%20cinnamon%3B%2Cc0) that both phrases were used approximately equally in books in 1890, but "cinnamon and nutmeg" has developed a strong lead since then, currently used more than twice as frequently as "nutmeg and cinnamon" in English books.

Comment: Having just said them aloud a few times, I find that I can say "nutmeg and cinnamon" more easily than "cinnamon and nutmeg". (Not that the latter is difficult.)

Comment: It may not be a linguistic reason, but may reflect e.g. the order in which ingredients are added during cooking.

Comment: Alphabetical order?

Comment: @nnnnnn - I can pronounce both with similar ease.

Comment: Oranges and lemons / Say the bells of St. Clement's shows what I consider the more mellifluous ordering. That may be partly down to familiarity. With 'cinnamon and nutmeg', I'd say it's a closer call. Perhaps partly due to a lack of familiarity.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that, if the claim is true, that it is an example of "ablaut reduplication". This is discussed at [Nursery Rhyme Central](https://nurseryrhymecentral.com/why-tick-tock-and-not-tock-tick-rule-of-ablaut-reduplication/#:%7E:text=We%20say%20tick-tock%20and%20not%20tock-tick%20because%20of,the%20back%20of%20the%20mouth.)"

> Have you ever stopped to wonder why we say tick-tock and not tock-tick? Or …ping-pong instead of pong-ping? … We say tick-tock and not tock-tick because of the ablaut reduplication rule. The rule refers to vowel changes in similar words and the order with which those vowels are said based on where the sounds are produced by the placement of the tongue – from the front to the back of the mouth.
>
> In which order do we say the vowels according to Ablaut Reduplication?
>
> The order of ablaut reduplication is generally I, A, O. But there are obviously more vowels and each vowel has a short and long sound, not to mention all the digraphs and trigraphs (this is where two or three vowels combine to make one sound) so as a rule of thumb we just continue to follow the front to back sound-making rule.
>
> … say the following words out loud: “Sit, set, sat, sought, sut”. You should feel that, as you continue to say the words, your tongue moves further back in your mouth.

In cinnamon and nutmeg, we have the vowel movement from /'sɪ/ to /ˈnʌ/

Comment: This is an excellent observation, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Cinnamon is generally more common and well-known than nutmeg among non-cooks, in my experience, and according to what I've read, we humans tend to list first the word that comes to mind first, or that we are more familiar with, or that we view as more relevant, when it comes to groupings or lists like these.

Source for the second claim: A study speculating on why "men and women" is more commonly used than "women and men", which I can't find at the moment.